# iOS - Push segue incorrectly coming from bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, segue

I have a push Segue with identifier "LoginSegue" that is meant to transition from "Login View Controller" to "View Controller."

Here is my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]
and here is the Segue:

[image: segue]

After a user successfully logs in, I call the following from within the LoginViewController:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: self)
```

in order to transition from the "Login View Controller" to the "View Controller."

I would expect this transition to occur from right-to-left as it is a Push segue, but for some reason it happens from bottom-to-top.

How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure LoginViewController is in navigationController? Check this by print(self.navigationController) in LoginViewController's viewDIdLoad method.

Comment: @PrajeetShrestha self.navigationController is nil. I created the navigation controller by selecting LoginViewController and doing Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont have **LoginViewController** in the navigationController. If you push another viewcontroller in any viewcontroller which is not inside navigationController it will present modally.

You might have set **LoginViewController** as a rootViewController of a **window** programitically or make sure navigationController is initialViewController not the **LoginViewController** in storyboard.

You can always check if any view controller is in navigationController or not by simply:
`print(self.navigationController)` inside viewDidLoad method of view controller.

Comment: You're exactly right. I had some code that set the rootViewController that I forgot about.